# How to use backbone.js to make a site also functional with client without JS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, seo

Take a look at http://www.usatoday.com, the website is made with backbone.js but work perfectly without.

I don't think they use somethings like http://phantomjs.org.

Someone know how they did that?

Thanks

P.S. I also send a mail to usatoday, if they answer and give me the permission I will report her what they say.

Comment: Doesn't work perfectly for me, at least on Chrome. I can see the layout and some graphics but all the loading gifs are permanent, nothings loads. The links don't work when being clicked, etc...

Comment: @elclanrs it doesn't work _perfectly_ for me either, but the important parts (eg. all the main content of the site) are accessible, with the problem being primarily with the sidebars.

Comment: sidebar are for navigation... so you don't care that much for SEO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use a technique called [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).

Essentially, this means you write the basic site *without* JS, and only add JavaScript on top of it later to improve the functionality.

There is nothing particularly special to it - the server simply sends the full HTML for the page which can be used to render the site instead of using Backbone to generate the markup on the fly from templates.

To be more specific about the techniques used in this case, it looks like they are generating the content mostly on the server even when using Ajax to load it.

When changing pages with JS enabled, they send the full page content markup from the server. Most likely this is done so that they can improve code reuse between the JS and non-JS versions of the site.

The HTML-block that is sent seems to contain some JSON. Most likely this is loaded for their client-side implementation so it knows what content you are currently viewing.

Comment: I know about progressive enhancement. But I want to know how they did it in this case. When you changing page I saw you get a complete webpage with a json inside. It's not a common way to use backbone.js.

Comment: @gagarine I updated the answer, hope this explains it a bit more.

Comment: OK. I get it. They don't load a model trough json but pick stuff in the html. They just have a flag "is ajax" than give the page without the block... that's it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805387/can-a-backbone-js-app-be-progressively-enhanced-and-crawlable-by-search-engines